# redirect inside redux action, url changes but not page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm trying to redirect to homepage after user logged in . Problem is that URL changes , but not page .
I have created custom history and imported in my action.js file. I have no idea why it doesn't work. Could you please help me.

history.js file

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

action.js file

```
import history from 'history.js';

export const goToHomePage = () => (dispatch) => {
  console.log('redirect to admin panel');
  history.push('/admin-panel');
};
```

In case you want see my router.js file

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <AppPath exact path="/" component={SignIn} layout={Layout} />
        <AppPath path="/admin-panel" component={Main} layout={Layout} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: `<BrowserRouter history={history}>`

Comment: @kinduser doesn't work

Comment: `import { Switch, Router } from 'react-router-dom';` BTW - what's the `AppPath`?

Comment: @kinduser It works!!!! thanks bro . P/S  I wrap my components with AppPath for private routes